# How to use YAML files using Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml, property-files

My application is spring based, and I would like to load yml file from a centralized server, but the unable to do so.

My yml file is like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: signed-in-web
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${server.url}
health:
  config:
    enabled: false
```

note: server.url is defined in vm options.
I had checked from rest client that properties are valid and available on the server.

Then I tried to copy it on a property file like this:
application.properties

```
LOCATION_SEARCH=${properties.app.api-key.location-search}
```

I had java configuration class like this:

```
@Profile("!test")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.company.frontend.*" })
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/qa_env.properties")
public class propertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("bootstrap.yml"));
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

I supposed that this will load the configuration like this:

```
@Value("${LOCATION_SEARCH}")
public static String LOCATION_SEARCH;
```

but I am getting null. Somehow I am not been able to find where the problem is. Will

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot you just need to call it `application-qa.yaml` and enable the `qa` profile. See also `spring.config` and `spring.profiles` in [Common Application Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Otherwise you just need to declare the yaml file in `@PropertySource` or `@PropertySources`.

Only if you don't want the properties in the global environment do you start needing to use `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` and `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` to manually bind them.